# Download folder?

Tags: download

[link](http://downloads.isee.biz/pub/files/igep-dsp-gst-framework-3_40_00/Graphics_SDK_4_05_00_03/GFX_Linux_SDK/OVG/SDKPackage/TrainingCourse/)

it shows a list of folders and I need to download one of them. How to download entire folder?

**UPDATED**

The link above shows the following picture:

[link](http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=48b7f95c2c0a1c4fcbb99694a261015b)

I want to download the whole folder 19_Font.

I know that if it is ftp protocol then I could open this link and download via ftp client. But I can't simply do the same for http.

I also tried grabbers:

- teleport pro under windows
- wget terminal command under mac os

But they didn't give me an appropriate result. So I deleted a mark about "mac os". Because it is enough difficult for me at all.

P.S. Especially for Dave M. This website rejects images posted from me and more than 2 links because of am too new to super user website. I hope the info above will be enough for you.

Comment: Folks are not fond of clicking random links to unknown locations.  Can you add more info to assist in getting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install wget with for example [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and then run:

```
wget -r -np http://downloads.isee.biz/pub/files/igep-dsp-gst-framework-3_40_00/Graphics_SDK_4_05_00_03/GFX_Linux_SDK/OVG/SDKPackage/TrainingCourse/01_Initialization/
```

-r is recursive and -np disables following links to parent directories.

Other options:

- -l inf sets the recursion depth to infinite instead of 5
- -nd downloads all files to the current directory instead of creating subdirectories
- -e robots=off ignores robots.txt
- -N disables redownloading files that have not been modified if you download the folder again later
- -A .jpg,.jpeg only accepts files that end with .jpg or .jpeg
- -R prefix\* rejects files that start with prefix
- -q is quiet

Comment: thank you so much. Your answer is almost the same thing I need. I only added "-R index\*" to this request to remove as much extra files as possible